# Android Fragment extends BaseRegisterFragment hides action bar when soft keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hello all i want a fragment that extends BaseRegisterFragment in that when i open keyboard my action bar hides
like
[image: Like] [image: This]

I don't want it

I have done this But no effects

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayoutname, container,
                false);
```

and this is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/masterLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/newsfeed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerMasterLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/five_dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/groupInfoHeaderLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgHeaderIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgBack"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtGroupInfo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/seven_dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgHeaderIcon"
                    android:text="@string/my_profile"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_user_picture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_picture" />
        <!-- </RelativeLayout> -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_display_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_enter_display_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/three_dp"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/voice_call"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

tried that?

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
    ...>
</activity>
```

Comment: it is fragment not activity so i will not have entry for that in manifest na?

Comment: but this fragment is attached to activity, try to set for it

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" that is not working

Comment: adjustResize resizes View if it is "resizable" e.g. ScrollView. you don't have any. try with adjustPAN